# How do I check the rendered width of an element in a ReactJS/Enzyme/PhantomJS Unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, phantomjs, enzyme

How do I check the width of a rendered element in a react JS unit test?  I'm using enzyme and PhantomJS.  Here's basically what I'm looking to do:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import EditableLabel from '../../../src/Common/EditableLabel/EditableLabel.jsx';

describe.only('./Controls/src/Common/EditableLabel/EditableLabel.jsx', () => {

    it('should resize the text box to at least the size of the label', () => {
        let wrapper = mount(<EditableLabel text={'SomeValue'} editing={true} />);
        let spanElements = wrapper.find('span.not-editing');
        let inputElements = wrapper.find('input[type="text"].editing');

        expect(inputElements.at(0).width()).to.be.at.least(spanElements.at(0).width());        
    });
```

});

Obviously, this will result in an error.  I'm hoping something like this is possible with my current setup.

Comment: Have you found the answer to your question?

Comment: You should not be automating UI tests, enzyme is simply not a tool that is built for this.

Comment: @Faissaloo Why not?

Comment: @TDK Because it makes your tests needlessly brittle for no reason. You should be testing for correct behaviour not page layout. If you test for page layout any time you need to redesign things your tests will break, even if the page still does the same thing.

Comment: @0x777C thanks for clarification. While writing unit tests for frontend it always confuses me what to include what not to include. If I should not be testing page layout then what is the purpose of snapshot testing? Shouldn't we write tests for layout to avoid unexpected changes?